# JSF own view for add and edit

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I want to build a JSF application. In this application I want to store books.

So, I created a `AddBook.xhtml` and `AddBookView` backing bean. Now I want to have a form where the user can edit books. The page basically has the same fields as `AddBool.xhtml`.

**My Question now:**

Should I reuse `AddBook.xhtml` for editing as well? Or should I create another `.xhtml` and backing bean called `EditBook.xhtml` and `EditBookView`?

Thanks

Comment: Why should you not? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: This question is **not** java(-se) or java-ee related. It is even partly jsf related. Replace .xhtml with .php and the tags with php and it is just as valid. It is about architecture of a web page. Two possible solutions: create an 'include' file that contains all the fields and use that in both views or use one view and enable/disable buttons based on the mode

Comment: Moreover, Stack Overflow is not for "Should I?" questions. Head to http://programmers.stackexchange.com or http://codereview.stackexchange.com, depending on how you (can) formulate the question.

Comment: @BalusC It might be good to point out what the different sites expect, or at least link to their help centers. I believe a lot of work needs to be done for this question to belong at either CR or Programmers.

Comment: How to formulate the question is already covered by "How to Ask" over there which should pop up when you ask a question for first time, or visit the Help center. If OP fails in this over there too, then it'll just get closed like here.

Comment: @BalusC this would be closed on programmers (and likely downvoted too). It's not at all clear what matthias is trying to do, this is pretty vague right now.

Comment: Indeed. As said, it depends on how OP (can) formulate the question. Of course the question is in its current form insuitable. That's why it's going to be closed instead of migrated.